# About the "Login with Facebook" mechanism

Tags: facebook, authentication, web

I am not sure I fully understand the "Login with Facebook" mechanism, and I need to make sure my understanding is correct (or perhaps it is not):

1. In order to deploy a "Login with Facebook" in my website, I ***must*** also have a Facebook application (?)
2. The first time anyone uses "Login with Facebook" in my website (assuming they are already logged in Facebook itself), they ***must*** go thru the Facebook dialog of approving the application. There's no way around that (?)
3. Anyone who successfully uses "Login with Facebook" in my website has his/her public Facebook data available to my website (?)

And the last one:

1. ***Legally*** speaking, do I have to name the button (or whatever) "Login with Facebook" (or similar), or can I name it any way I want (say, "Go ahead and work")?

Comment: Last question should be #4 of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Correct.  That Facebook application is how Facebook tracks information about you to provide to the users, where to redirect users after authorizing your application, etc.  It's essentially the integration point between your application and Facebook.
2. Correct.  They may also be prompted to re-approve again in the future.
3. You would have access to anything which they permit you to have access.  By default this includes basic profile data, but there are [lots of other permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/) available as well.  Keep in mind that, if you request additional permissions, they may allow basic permissions but then pick-and-choose which additional permissions.  So it's not always a safe assumption that just because they've logged in with Facebook to your application that they've authorized everything.

And the last one:

1. `"Legally speaking..."` - Not our department, sorry.  For any legal advice you'll want to consult an attorney.

Answer (score 1):

**1.)** Yes you **must** have and App ID and App Secret from your Facebook App. ([Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/apps))

**2.)** And yes again, you can not work around that dialog, a user must grand your app the permission to go ahead.

**3.)** You will get the data that you Required via your Application. Then in turn this request is shown in the Dialog when a user log's in to your Website, if they grand you the access, its all yours :).

**4.)** You can name the button anything you want :)